# Prove that limit $\lim_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^2\cdot y}{x^2 + y^3}$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)}\frac{x^2\cdot y}{x^2 + y^3}$$
I was trying to find two paths along x-y plane that when followed lead to different limits, but I always got 0.

Comment: I have added an answer to the linked duplicate. There I try to show you the how and why for a systematic choice of a path to show the non-existence of the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):f\left(\frac1{n^3},-\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^4}\right)=\frac{n^2-n^4}{3 n^4-3 n^2+1}$$and that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2-n^4}{3 n^4-3 n^2+1}=-\frac13\neq0.$$